# Slow ecryptfs mount

Tags: troubleshooting, ecryptfs, nas

If I create an encrypted share (internally done via `ecryptfs`) on a synology disk station DS109 (DSM 4.1), mounting is very slow (approx 40 seconds).

It doesn't matter if I do it via the web-interface or via `synoshare --enc_mount myencryptedshare mypassphrase`. It also doesn't matter if there is data in the share or not, same 40 seconds for an empty share and for one with 1GB in it.

Mounting with `encfs` works perfectly, so I guess it might not be an CPU issue, since `encfs` seems to be a bit slower in general than `ecryptfs`.

Any idea what may be wrong?

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I debug this?

Try to `strace` the command. That should show the syscalls the program is making, which could help you narrow it down.